# Decoding the UDP Packet received from C++ to qt code

Tags: c++, qt

I am not able to decode the packet received from udp socket,
how to  decode the nested structures sent from c++ to qt udp socket

i have struct likes this

```
 struct stCardInfo
{
    unsigned short nsCardType;
    unsigned short nsNoOfSignals;
    unsigned short nsStatus;
};

struct stErrorInfo
{
    unsigned short nsErrorType;
    char ErrorInfo[8];
};
struct stInitHealthCheck
{
    unsigned short nsNoOfCards;
    unsigned short nsCardType;
    QVector<stCardInfo*> lsCardInfo;
    QVector<stErrorInfo*> lsErrorInfo;
};
```

iam getting the bytearray data need to convert to the nested structures

Comment: In order to do it correctly you'll need to know the format in which the data was transmitted.  To find that out you'll either need to find where that information is documented, or ask the person who wrote the sending program, or (if all else fails) read the source code of the sending program to see how it converts data structures into bytes (and then do the opposite operations in your own program)

Comment: You are passing pointers `QVector<stCardInfo*>` instead of objecs. You will get a memory corruption immideatelly after decoding. And if you need a help you should provide your transfer and receiving code (how do you work with sockets)..

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading from a `Qt` UDP socket, it means you are reading from an application level. You can use `QUdpSocket::readDatagram` function to get the message. To interpret the message you need to know the format. If you are not sure about how exactly data has been sent, you can try playing around with `wireshark` to get an inside view of how data has been sent. Then you can do necessary parsing and carry on.

Note `QUdpSocket::readDatagram` returns data as `char *`. See at the `Qt` documentation for more details.